# How to maintain a global list to uniquely loop in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, loops

I need to filter operation in some of the nodes which are duplicate (on a key)
Following are my data file.

data.xml

```
<root>
    <node name="item1" />
    <node name="item2" />
    <node name="item3" />
    <node name="item4" />
</root>
```

in file item1.xml

```
<item>
 <group>A</group>
</item>
```

item2.xml

```
<item>
 <group>B</group>
</item>
```

item3.xml

```
<item>
 <group>B</group>
</item>
```

item4.xml

```
<item>
 <group>D</group>
</item>
```

XSLT File

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/node">
     <xsl:variable name="itemName"   select="@name"/>
     <xsl:variable name="groupName"  select="document($itemName)/item/group"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('Group ',$groupName)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

output

> Group A
>   Group B
>   Group B
>   Group C

Desired output

> Group A
>   Group B
>   Group C

Here item 2 and 3 are of same group according to their group attribute so I have to only print the group name of any of them.

Comment: I don't think the `<xsl:key>` method works cross-document, but perhaps that's part of the answer.

Comment: @cbeer Can anything be done if I put the attributes in the single file ?  e.g <root>
    <node name="item1" group="A" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<root>
    <node name="item1" group="A"/>
    <node name="item2" group="B"/>
</root>
```

If the group name itself can be somehow put in the main XML file as an attribute the distinct nodes can be found as follows

```
   <xsl:for-each select="/root/node[not(@group = preceding-sibling::node/@group)]">
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Above select expression would ignore any node which has been encountered earlier (belongs to one of the preceding nodes)

PS: This is not the solution the question which involves multiple XML files. Any answer in that line would be useful.